# Android TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText cursor color problem

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

[image][image: Problem]

I have this problem, after the xxx is the cursor in violet, I want to know the name of that drop cursor, I want to change the color to match my theme. I read many forums and documentation, the only I find was cursorDrawable, but is not that. Please help me with the correct name to search or the solution.
Thanks
PD: The violet color of that THING is not in my styles or colors.

Comment: Post your code pls

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The color is based on **`colorPrimary`**.

If you want to override the colorPrimary you can use:

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout                
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.TextInputEditText.Outlined"
    ....>
```

with:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.TextInputEditText.Outlined" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/...</item>
</style>
```

[image]

If you want to override only the cursor you can use:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.TextInputEditText.Outlined" parent="">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/...</item>
</style>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I mean the drop that is below the cursor, that is what i need to change. I add another image showing exactly what I mean

Comment: @GastonFassiLavalle The drop has the same color of the cursor.

Comment: Thanks, now i need to find where is that color i try     <color name="colorPrimary">#000</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#000</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#000</color>  and still is violet not black. I will try the override in styles, but I want to learn where is that violet color coming from

Comment: @GastonFassiLavalle The violet (`#6200EE`) is the default color defined by the [Material Theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Color.md). In your `styles.xml` just add in your app theme the `colorPrimary` attribute. Something like: `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>`

Comment: Thanks that works, i was looking another way but is better to override. Many thanks.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti any idea how to do it using Material3?