# Android TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText cursor color

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme, android-styles, material3

I want to change the cursor (or caret) color, just like in this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63636374/android-textinputlayout-and-textinputedittext-cursor-color-problem), but in Material 3.

This is my verion of the material library:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
```

This is how my layout looks like:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/brands_input_layout"
    style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu.Honk"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/size_medium"
    android:paddingEnd="44dp"
    android:theme="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu.Honk"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/hide_show_brands_icon"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/description_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And this is my theme file:

```xml
<style name="Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu.Honk">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/textDropdownBoxStrokeColor</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/textDropdownBoxStrokeColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/textDropdownBoxStrokeColor</item>
    <item name="endIconTint">@color/dropdown_menu_arrow</item>
</style>
```

##### Solution 1 (did not work):

```xml
<style name="ThemeOverlay.SmartHabit.TextInputEditText.FilledBox.Dense" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.TextInputEditText.FilledBox.Dense">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorSecondary</item>
</style>
```

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/description_input"
    style="@style/ThemeOverlay.SmartHabit.TextInputEditText.FilledBox.Dense"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
```

##### Solution 2 (did not work):

```xml
<style name="ThemeOverlay.SmartHabit.TextInputEditText.FilledBox.Dense" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.TextInputEditText.FilledBox.Dense">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorSecondary</item>
</style>
```

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/description_input"
    style="@style/ThemeOverlay.SmartHabit.TextInputEditText.FilledBox.Dense"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
```

##### Solution 3 (did not work):

Create a custom cursor on drawable folder:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorSecondary" />
    <size android:width="2dp" />
</shape>
```

And use it like this:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/description_input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor" />
```

##### Solution 4 (did not work):

I already trying doing this, acording to the [Material 3 Documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextField.md#input-text-attributes-set-on-the-textinputedittext), but that did not worked:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/description_input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences" 
    app:cursorColor="@color/myColor" />
```

Comment: This may help : https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextField.md#input-text-attributes-set-on-the-textinputedittext

Comment: @DrHowdyDoo thank you so much! I already tried something based in this doc, but did not work. I added that to my question, but if you feel like I did something wrong, please, help me understant how to fix it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use it in the theme, not style, from my TextInputLayout:

```xml
<style name="TextInputLayoutAppearance" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorSecondary</item>
</style>
```

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/description_input_layout" 
    style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense.SmartHabits"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/size_extra_large"
    android:hint="@string/description"
    android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutAppearance"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/add_habit_button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/description_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: I think you again accidently used style instead of theme in above solution

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

Add this in style.xml file

`<style name="EditTextThemeOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"> <item name="colorAccent">@color/black</item> </style>`

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/EditTextThemeOverlay"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Name"
            app:hintEnabled="true"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/name">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text" />
```